# Developing module and using it in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, python-module

I'm trying to develop a python module, which I then want to use in Spyder.

Here is how my files are organized in my module :

```
testing_the_module.py
myModule
-> __init__.py
-> sql_querying.py #contains a function called sql()
```

`testing_the_module.py` contains :

```
import myModule
print(myModule.sql_querying.sql(query = "show tables")) # how this function works is not relevant
```

`__init__.py` contains

```
import myModule.sql_querying
```

When I use the command line, it works :

```
> python3 .\testing_the_module.py
[{
    'query': 'show tables',
    'result': ['table1', 'table2']
}]
```

It also works if I use the python console :

```
> python3
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import myModule
>>> print(myModule.sql_querying.sql(query = "show tables"))
[{
    'query': 'show tables',
    'result': ['table1', 'table2']
}]
```

However, when using Spyder, I can't get it to work. Here is what I get when I run (with F9) each of those lines :

```
import myModule
# no error message
print(myModule.sql_querying.sql(query = "show tables"))
```

> AttributeError: module 'myModule' has no attribute 'sql_querying'

Any idea of why and how to make it work in Spyder ?

---

Edit to answer comment :

```
In [665]: sys.path
Out[665]: 
['',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\fmalaussena\\.ipython']
```

Comment: This should work. Do you have another `myModule.py` or `myModule` folder with an `__init__.py` that could conflict in the import? What is `sys.path` is saying in the ipython console?

Comment: Nothing that could conflict, no. I edited the end of the question to include the result of `sys.path`